# Android Orientation for ACTION.VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent

How can we fix orientation to `portrait` when we load a website such as twiter using `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control how another app functions through an intent, you can just tell it what to open.

You could make your own activity using a WebView, but you'll probably have to do a lot of work to get it to be as functional as the browser -- depends on your requirements I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Put android:screenOrientation="portrait" in the manifest for the correct intent.

Comment: This is not going to work man. cause  as far as I understand this intent has no reference(at least direct) in manifest, in this case.